# How do i staticly assign a ip in CentOS7

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip

Trying to follow the guides online but i have no ifcfg-Eth0 or ensp3? or what ever all i have i ifcfg-lo and the contents look nothing like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Hwv6OcfazI https://i.stack.imgur.com/os7fv.png also been trying to assign ip in Ubuntu 18.04 which doesn't use ect/network/interface no more it uses Netplan and even after i edit that and apply it i never have internet access. why on earth is linux so difficult to give addresses, i also tried the GUI way but i can never get online after. Is it something to do with Vmware?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You must add nic to your VM and centos must have driver for this nic. After that you can ask a question in "Unix & Linux Stack Exchange" (how to configure network connection in centos7) or try to configure it youself.
I recommend to do something like:

```
[root@centos7]# nmcli con show 
NAME    UUID                            TYPE      DEVICE 
enp0s3  d77bd8ad-ec13-4442-bb2b-ccee7a697552  ethernet  enp0s3 
[root@centos7minimal network-scripts]# nmcli con mod "enp0s3" ipv4.address "192.168.1.2/25, 192.168.1.3/32" ipv4.gateway "192.168.1.1" ipv4.dns "192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8" 
[root@centos7minimal network-scripts]# nmcli con up enp0s3 
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
```